# Slow SQL connections with Windows Authentication when mixed mode authentication is enabled

Tags: sql-server

We are experiencing slow SQL connections from clients when using Windows Authentication. If we use SQL authentication the connection is fast.

We have tried using the hostname and the IP address when making the connection, checking DNS for all the correct entries, made entries in the host file on the client computers, and numerous other things and none of them made a difference.

After a lot of testing we disabled Mixed Mode authentication on the SQL server and once we did Windows Authentication logins were fast. However once we re-enabled Mixed Mode authentication the Windows Authentication logins because very slow again.

Has anyone seen this behavior before where Windows Authentication is slow when Mixed Mode authentication is enabled on the SQL server?

Comment: How are you measuring the speed of logging in?

Comment: We ideally need more details. Any resource groups? Any login triggers? What is "slow" and what is "fast"? What do the XE sources say? What does an ETW trace on cpu say?

Comment: What we are seeing is slow, 20 second+, connections from SSMS to the database. A "fast connection" takes about 2 seconds. This is where we are measuring the connection speed however we are seeing the slow connectivity from applications as well. New findings. First, it is only slow from Windows 10 and 11 computers. Anything running a server OS is fine. Second, it is only slow to the first server in the cluster, not the second. We have failed over to the second node however would like to resolve this. CPU and memory resources are not taxed on the servers with no resource constraints that we see.